# "How can I find the pixels belonging to a segmented object? I'm using SAM - Segment Anything Model

Tags: python, image-processing, image-segmentation

Good morning everyone,

I've a question regarding Meta's new tool, SAM, specifically concerning the pixels of a mask. I've been experimenting with SAM to segment a bunch of grapes. As you can see in the attached code, I'm iteratively moving the input point across my image and subsequently displaying the predicted mask for that point. When I move my point over a new grape, I'd like to change the pixels values associated with that grape. Basically, I need to identify which pixels belong to the grape where my point is currently positioned.

Can anyone assist me with this?

```
input_label = np.array([1])
row_range = image.shape[0]-800
col_range = image.shape[1]-300
for i in range(0,row_range,200):
  for j in range(0,col_range,200):
    input_point = np.array([[j, i]])
    masks, scores, logits = predictor.predict(
        point_coords=input_point,
        point_labels=input_label,
        multimask_output=False,
    )
    
    show_images(image, masks, scores, input_point, input_label)
```

Comment: Who/where/what is *"Meta"* please? We can't see any grapes, so we don't know what you are referring to ‍♂️ Your code is incomplete - please see [mcve]. Thank you. Please add extra info into question using [edit] rather than comments.